# Add class to parent div if there has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass

Trying to add class to parent div `<div class="widget-content">` if `.widget-content li a` has specific class `.ifthis`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="widget-content">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/slycolor" class="ifthis"> <b>This Text Should Red</b></a>
</li>

<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/slycolor" class="ifthis"> <b>This Text Should Red</b></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have tried This:

```
$('.widget-content li a').has('.ifthis').parent('.widget-content').addClass('social-sidebar');
```

But not working, see this example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8ohs9us/5/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select children which have class `ifthis` then select it's parent using **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** or **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

```
$('.widget-content li a.ifthis').parents('.widget-content').addClass('social-sidebar');
```

OR

```
$('.widget-content li a.ifthis').closest('.widget-content').addClass('social-sidebar');
```

Your code is not working because,

1. **[`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)** will only check that it's descendant has contain that selector, you need **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** instead.
2. **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** will only select immediate parent , so you should use **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** or **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**.

With your code :

```
$('.widget-content li a').filter('.ifthis').parents('.widget-content').addClass('social-sidebar');
```

Comment: Good, also `.has()` returns a boolean, not a jQuery object you can operate on

Comment: @AmmarCSE : nop, has() returns jquery object , https://api.jquery.com/has/. I think you were talking about is()

Comment: @PranavCBalan, my silly mistake. Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$('a.ifthis').closest('div.widget-content').addClass('social-sidebar');
```

Or:

```
$('.ifthis').closest('.widget-content').addClass('social-sidebar');
//if only a elements have .ifthis and only div elements have .widget-content
```

Or:

```
$('.widget-content:has(.ifthis)').addClass('social-sidebar');
```

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/closest/
https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

> **.closest( selector ) -- Returns: jQuery**
>
> **Description:** For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

**:has() Selector**

> **jQuery( ":has(selector)" ) -- Returns: jQuery**
>
> **Description:** Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.